# Issues with passing values taken from a table into a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to pass values taken from a table into a modal.
The first thing I did was When a button is clicked on a particular row, the `<td>` values in that row is displayed as an `alert`. That worked perfectly but I want to go further to remove the `alert` and make the `<td>` values appear in a modal when that particular button is clicked. I intend using a bootstrap modal.

The first section of code works perfectly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
    $("#dtBasicExample").on('click', '.btn-outline-warning', function() {
        // get the current row
        var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

        var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st TD value
        var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // get current row 2nd TD
        var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text();
        var col4 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text(); // get current row 3rd TD
        var data = "The requisition with number " +
                    col1 + " initiated by " + col2 + " of " + col4 + " " + col3 + " has been queried";
        alert(data);

    });
})
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
    $("#dtBasicExample").on('click', '.btn-outline-warning', function() {
        // get the current row
        var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

        var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st TD value
        var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // get current row 2nd TD
        var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text();
        var col4 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text(); // get current row 3rd TD
        var data = "The requisition with number " +
            col1 + " initiated by " + col2 + " of " + col4 + " " + col3 + " has been queried";
        document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body').innerHTML = data;

    });
})
```

Here's my modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="basicExampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
    </td>
    <td>PO13238</td>
    <td>Ibese</td>
    <td>Yusuf Jimoh</td>
    <td>Naira</td>
    <td>150,00</td>
    <td>
        <p><a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" href="#ex1" rel="modal:open"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" href="#ex1" rel="modal:open"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm m-0 waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" href="#ex1" rel="modal:open" onclick="remove()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; you have a `tr` randomly placed in the middle of the HTML, instead of within a `table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is because [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an `HTMLCollection`, not a single node, so `document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body').innerHTML` cannot work.

Instead, you need to select the desired node from the collection and set the `innerHTML` on that element.

Instead of

`document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body').innerHTML = data;`

use

`document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].innerHTML = data;`

Note: I'm using `0` as only one modal is present, you may need to change that index if you have multiple modals/modal-bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes in your code to make it work. Additionally, the problem line seems to be this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body').innerHTML = data;
```

document.getElementsByClassName() returns the array, so get the first element of array to set the data

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-outline-warning', function() {
    // get the current row
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

    var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st TD value
    var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // get current row 2nd TD
    var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text();
    var col4 = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text(); // get current row 3rd TD
    var data = "The requisition with number " +
      col1 + " initiated by " + col2 + " of " + col4 + " " + col3 + " has been queried";
    alert(data);
    document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].innerHTML = data;
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" style="border:solid 1px;">



  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="dtBasicExample">
        </td>
        <td>PO13238</td>
        <td>Ibese</td>
        <td>Yusuf Jimoh</td>
        <td>Naira</td>
        <td>150,00</td>
        <td>
          <p><a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" href="#ex1" rel="modal:open"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a></p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" href="#ex1" rel="modal:open"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm m-0 waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm m-0 waves-effect" href="#ex1" rel="modal:open" onclick="remove()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are binding table element such as tr, td in the web page. But your tr and td have no parent table tag that can be an issue. You can make empty table with an id or you can also get whole table data from jquery with starting and ending table tag

Comment: i didn't post the complete code here. thanks for your assistance